# Как вывести ник отправителя сообщения в чат?

Tags: php, javascript

У меня на сайте стоит чат, но сообщения без ника отправителя. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Вот сам чат :

```
<iframe name='chatWindow' id='chatWindow' src ="iframe.php" width="1265" height="400">
</iframe>
<form action="iframe.php" method="post" name="form" target='chatWindow' >
<p>Сообщение:<input name="message" type="text" size="75" maxleght="255">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="OK">
</p>
<br>
```

A это iframe:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['message']))
{
$message = $_POST ['message'];
}
$db = mysql_connect("sql-4.zerver.ru","bakugan609","s026y8pjtl");
mysql_select_db("bakugan609",$db);
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (message) VALUES ('$message')");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages");
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ){
echo "<br>";
echo "{$row['message']}
";
}
?>
```

Comment: а у вас не сохраняется в базу ника сообщения. вот сохраните вместе с сообщением только в другой ячейке и потом вытаскивайте. только ник надо где то иметь уже. или в куках или в переменной сессии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам придется сначала ник сохранить. Для этого в таблице, где месседж хванится, сделайте еще и место для ника и потом пишите его:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (message,nick) VALUES ('$message','$nick')");
//ну и вывод тогда будет
echo "{$row['nick']}: {$row['message']}";
```

Comment: Нее , у меня есть отдельная таблица с пользователями как с той таблицы вытягивать?

Comment: ну все равно надо с меседжем писать хотя бы ID от ячейки где ник лежит или чтото еще что удостоверять будет что запись именно от него. хотя я советую именно ник писать. потому что записав ИД вы должны будете опять таки в базе смотреть а какой там ник на нем и так выводить, это лишняя нагрузка на базу